# How do I save and restore agent breeds in a file?

Tags: io, netlogo

I want to save and restore a set of turtles in a file. I have something like this:

```
breed [squares square]
breed [circles circle]

squares-own [side-length]
circles-own [radius]

to save-agents
  file-open "test"

  file-write count turtles 
  ask turtles [
    file-write xcor
    file-write ycor
    file-write breed
  ]
  ask squares [
    file-write side-length
  ]
  ask circles [
    file-write radius
  ]

  file-close
end

to restore-agents
  file-open "test"

  let n file-read

  crt n

  ask turtles [
    set xcor file-read
    set ycor file-read
    set breed file-read  ;; Right here I get an error "Expected a constant. (line number 1,
  ]                      ;; character x) error while turtle y running FILE-READ"

  ask squares [
    set side-length file-read
  ] 
  ask circles [
    set radius file-read
  ]
```

Looking at the file, I see the breeds are stored as unquoted character strings. It doesn't matter what I try to read the breed variable as; I get an error just manually going through a bunch of `file-read` statements.

I suppose I could intentionally code the breed as a string that I later interpret using a whole bunch of nested `ifelse` blocks (yuk). But it appears that the way NetLogo writes the breed variable is the same way it writes other constants like `true` and `false`. Is this a NetLogo bug? Is there an (elegant) work-around?

On further thought, I could count and store each kind of agent individually so when I go to restore I could `create squares number-of-squares`, etc. but I was really hoping not to have to handle every possible kind of breed this way. Suggestions?

Thanks,

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

The [`runresult`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#runresult) primitive can help you here: it allows to run code stored in a string.

If you save your breed using

```
file-write (word breed)
```

to make sure that NetLogo puts quotes around it, you can later restore it like this:

```
let breed-as-string file-read
set breed runresult breed-as-string
```

There are also other possible approaches for saving and restoring turtles:

- [`export-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#export-world) and [`import-world`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#import-world) might be overkill here, since they save and restore the whole state of the NetLogo world, but they may be useful in other circomstances.
- The [`nw:save-graphml`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#save-graphml) and [`nw:load-graphml`](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#load-graphml) from the [NW extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#readme) can also be used for that. Their primary purpose is to deal with networks (i.e., turtles *and* links) but they won't complain if you have only turtles to save and restore.

**Edit:**

Here is a full example using `runresult`:

```
breed [squares square]
breed [circles circle]

to save-and-restore-breeds

  clear-all
  create-squares 2
  create-circles 2

  if file-exists? "test" [ file-delete "test" ]

  ; save agents:
  file-open "test"
  file-write count turtles
  ask turtles [ file-write (word breed) ]
  file-close

  clear-all

  ; restore agents:
  file-open "test"
  let n file-read
  crt n [
    let breed-as-string file-read
    set breed runresult breed-as-string
  ]
  file-close

  show [ breed ] of turtles

end
```

Comment: This does not appear to work for me. Have you tried it in NL 5.05? When I restore I get the following error:
    The name BREED-AS-STRING is already defined
    error while turtle 3 running RUNRESULT
      called by procedure RESTORE-SCENARIO
      called by Button 'restore'

Comment: Could it be just a matter of using `set` instead of `let`?